# What to do with java-based math demos?

Tags: education, online-resources

A large volume of mathematical demos were written in Java. Then came security warnings of all sorts. Currently it does not seem viable to direct students to such demos.

Do you think an organization such [MAA](http://www.maa.org/about-maa/maa-history/mathdl) would show an interest in trying to preserve this endeavor  by collecting such content and act as a central clearing house? (The centralization lowers the obstacle the students will have in utilizing the demos as they need to declare just one site as trusted.)

Comment: Isn't GeoGebra also a Java application?

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic   I do not know, but one does not  get a security warning while running GeoGebra or apps based on it. Chrome, which does not support Java apps, does not complain about GG.

Comment: Personally I haven't found a solution to this and just given up on them, or look for sites rewriting them in JavaScript. It's among the most cutting examples of digital dark-agification that I know.

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic To correct myself I just saw some pages where the app is claimed to be GeoGebra-based but it looks like standard java app and exhibits same issues. Compare  [not-problematic](http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/GeoGebraCalculus/derivative_at_a_point.html) with  [problematic](http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/GeoGebraCalculus/derivative_at_a_point.html).

Comment: This is a good question, but not a mathematical one. The same can be asked about Java-based X demos, for any value of X. In a nutshell, you are asking how the users of web browsers should be told to run Java applets, given the security settings that these browsers have nowadays. I think the question fits on [su].